# CSS: form is overflowing outside parent div with no explanation

Tags: html, css, forms, grid, size

I create a simple page that only contains a header (h1), a grid and a simple form. The header takes the space I expect it to take, the grid too, but the form seems to occupy space outside the grid, despite the entire code being inside it. I can't understand why this is happening and changing properties such as margin, padding on the form tag doesn't help. Please see video:

https://streamable.com/2lbmsz

My code looks like this:

```
<h1>{{ content.title }}</h1>
<div class="grid12">
    <form method="POST" action="/catalogue/add">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="grid2 field">
                {{ form.asset_name.label }}
            </div>
            <div class="grid4 field">
                {{ form.asset_name }}
            </div>
            <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.asset_name.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>
        </div>
        ...
        <div class="row">
            <div class="grid2 field">
                {{ form.asset_short_description.label }}
            </div>
            <div class="grid4 field">
                {{ form.asset_short_description }}
            </div>
            <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.asset_short_description.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>
        </div>
        {{ form.submit }}
    </form>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what a fix would be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `max-width: ;` to css file.

If you can send the CSS i will edit here so we can fix it